# Perfect alignment of triangles with Quartz2D drawing

Tags: ios, drawing, quartz-2d

I want to draw two general triangles in 2D space in such way that they share one edge, using Quartz2D. I'm using this code for the drawing:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    Triangle *t1 = [triangles objectAtIndex:0];
    Triangle *t2 = [triangles objectAtIndex:1];

    [self fillTriangle:t1 inContext:context];
    [self fillTriangle:t2 inContext:context];
}

- (void) fillTriangle:(Triangle *)t inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, t.p1.p.x, t.p1.p.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, t.p2.p.x, t.p2.p.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, t.p3.p.x, t.p3.p.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, t.p1.p.x, t.p1.p.y);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, t.color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

where `Triangle` is a `NSObject` subclass holding three points and a color.

The problem is that even when they share two points, there's a "space" between them when I fill them by this code, as shown in the image:

[image: Two triangles sharing one edge]

**Question:** Anyone knows how to get rid of the space so there's a seamless transition from one triangle to another with no line or whatever between them? I'd like to keep using Quartz2D but I'm glad for any help. Thanks!

**EDIT:** There were answers showing that the problem is caused by sub-pixel anti-aliasing, and adding the line

```
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, NO);
```

to the `fillTriangle` method solved that. But it's not the result I'd like to see - I don't like it being aliased, as shown in the second picture.

[image: Two triangles aliased]

**Question updated:** do you know, how to solve both of the problems, that is, keeping the image clean with no ugly aliasing but no space between the triangles?

**EDIT2:** So, as was pointed in an answer, I could add the line stroke code, remove the antialiasing flag and the stroke would fill the space. Here's a last image to show what happened:

[image]

Notice the lines overlapping outside of the box. I was wondering what the cause might have been, and it disappeared when I **set the width to 0.5f** (since retina, that translates to 1px and that's probably what the responder thought), and that really solved the whole thing. Thanks to all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are drawing using antialiasing. disable it for your context via

```
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
```

and everything should be fine.

EDIT:
in case of antialiasing is needed (your updated multicolor example), you could try to not only fill the triangles but also stroke their border in the same color with a line width of 1px:

```
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.5f);
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

of course you should remove the `CGContextSetShouldAntialias` line in that case. It's a simple solution but may not be the best performance wise, since the path has to be stroked and filled.

Comment: Similar info as the other answer, but you posted a code which solved it! Thanks :) EDIT: actually, it solved the problem of a transparent line between triangles, but now it looks bad with different colors. I'll update the question.

Comment: updated the answer with a possible solution for the edited question.

Comment: thank you very much for the updated answer! I've updated the question too - this helps, in a way, but is not perfect unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting antialiasing effect of sub pixel rendering. This happens when things are not at integral points.

But more to the point if these need to share an edge and are the same color, just draw a quadrilateral instead.

Comment: although I didn't mention that (and sorry for that one), the colors don't have to be the same, so drawing quadrilateral won't solve the problem, but you were right though that I'm getting an antialiasing effect of sub-pixel rendering! Point for that :) thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thought so. Keep in mind that Quartz is basically a PDF drawing model. That means it draws in layers (well, procedurally) front to back. This is just like printing. (Again PDF)

Comment: This means you can layer things. It may be convenient to draw a triangle on top of a quadrilateral. That way the sub-pixel rendering of angled edges is controlled. You know what color is aliased against what color.

Comment: It's kind of a trick. Similar to making gif or png images with transparency. The effect is more pronounced when you are using various compositing operation modes.

Comment: To solve the aliasing problem you really are limited by hardware at some point. So antialiasing drawing triangle on top of quadrilateral takes care of the right pixels being blended colors to trick the eye into seeing a sharper line. But, some angles will naturally be more jagged than others so you want to be pixel aligned on right angles if possible and antialiased and drawing on top of the color to blend with to address angled lines.